# ZXing on Android scanning 2D codes but throwing NotFoundException for 1D codes

Tags: java, android, camera, barcode, zxing

I've integrated ZXing 3.1.1 in my app to enable it to take pictures of barcodes and act on the input data.

I'm able to scan two dimensional codes (like QR Codes and Data Matrices) with it, but all one dimensional barcodes are failing to scan.

My code is as follows:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){
    BinaryBitmap bbm = BinaryBitmapFromJpegData(data); // Impl. below
    MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
    Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> hints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
    Collection<BarcodeFormat> possible_types = new ArrayList<BarcodeFormat>();

    possible_types.add(BarcodeFormat.UPC_A);
    possible_types.add(BarcodeFormat.UPC_E);
    possible_types.add(BarcodeFormat.EAN_8);
    possible_types.add(BarcodeFormat.EAN_13);
    possible_types.add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
    possible_types.add(BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX);

    hints.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMAT, possible_types);
    hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);

    try {
        Result result = reader.decode(bbm, hints);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Found barcode: " + result.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No barcode found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("myapp", "Not found! (" + e.getMessage() + ")", e);
    }
}

private BinaryBitmap BinaryBitmapFromJpegData(byte[] data){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    int[] intArray = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];

    bitmap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), intArray);
    BinaryBitmap bbm = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

    return bbm;
}
```

The stack trace that isn't very helpful either:

[image: stack trace]

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm testing this on a Samsung Galaxy Note 2.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from logcat?

Comment: @bstar55: There isn't a stack trace - added a screenshot in the OP above.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I looked at the documentation, and it looks like that exception occurs when no decodable barcode is found in the image.

Comment: Yep. Been reading over that. I just find it odd that it scans 2D codes without fail and not one in a hundred 1D codes don't register.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are the barcodes you're trying to scan coming from? Printed labels?  Off the screen?

Comment: I've tried both paper and my monitor. Same issue for both.

Comment: I'm still figuring things out, but I tried taking the photo at a different orientation and it worked - I'll post answers once I figure it all out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that the camera was shooting at a sideways orientation, and ZXing doesn't appear to check for 1D barcodes at an angle.

Rotating the bitmap in 90 degree intervals fixed the issue for me.

The new functions are as follows:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){
    MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
    Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> hints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
    Collection<BarcodeFormat> possible_types = new ArrayList<BarcodeFormat>();

    possible_types.add(BarcodeFormat.UPC_A);
    possible_types.add(BarcodeFormat.UPC_E);
    possible_types.add(BarcodeFormat.EAN_8);
    possible_types.add(BarcodeFormat.EAN_13);
    possible_types.add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
    possible_types.add(BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX);

    hints.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMAT, possible_types);
    hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);

    Result result = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = BinaryBitmapFromJpegData(data, i * 90);

        try {
            result = reader.decode(bitmap, hints);
            break;
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {}
    }

    if(result == null){
        Toast.makeText(context, "No Barcode Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Found barcode: " + result.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private BinaryBitmap BinaryBitmapFromJpegData(byte[] data, int rotation){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

    if(rotation != 0){
        bitmap = RotateBitmap(bitmap, rotation);
    }

    int[] intArray = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
    bitmap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), intArray);
    BinaryBitmap bbm = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

    return bbm;
}

public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle){
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Comment: You might try modifying you camera settings to capture preview frames with a 90 degree rotation.  Then you can avoid this hack :-)

Comment: You're right about capturing at the right angle - however, it's important because some of the barcodes the app will be scanning will be at angles that would cause this issue to happen again.